# Can two unequal positive charges collide?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, collision

If we have two *equal* positive charges, say A and B seperated by a huge distance, where A is moving with some velocity *v* from and B is at rest and free to move, we say that there exists a distance of closest approach between them.

However, if we have two *unequal* positive charges of *equal* masses, A and B, with again A moving with some velocity *v* and B is at rest and free to move, collision will take place and A will stop moving and B will start moving with the velocity *v*.

My question is, how is it possible for two unequal positive charges to collide? Won't there be even a slightest amount repulsion between them that will prevent them from colliding?

Comment: You are combining conservation of momentum between uncharged bodies with electrostatic repulsion of charged bodies.  Your second paragraph indicates that you are drawing conclusions that are probably not valid.

Comment: In the second paragraph, these are two of the homework sites which have concluded what I have written, hence had a doubt. <https://www.sarthaks.com/552535/particles-equal-mass-with-unequal-positive-charges-free-move-initially-away-from-each-other> <https://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/two-particle-x-and-y-of-equal-mass-and-with-unequal-positive/electrostatic-potential-and-capacitance/10783623>

Comment: Is the charge initially at rest held at rest by some other force while the other charge moves toward it, such as mechanical or crystalline structure, or is it free to move ?

Comment: @BillN It is free to move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the items collide doesn't depend on the equality or unequality of the charges. Collision (or not) depends on the

1. impact parameter (line of undeviated velocity), which must be smaller than the combined radii of the particles ($r_1+r_2$), and
2. the initial kinetic energy of the moving particle, and
3. the product ($Q_1Q_2$) of the charges.

The easiest to process is if the impact parameter is zero (a direct/head-on collision). Then a collision will occur if the initial kinetic energy is greater than limiting electrical potential energy $$\frac{Q_1Q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0(r_1+r_2)}$$

Equality or unequality of massesand and charges are generally not a factor in whether or not they collide.

Comment: Got it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The repulsion between them is what mediates the collision.

Your second scenario isn't much different from the first.  The incoming charge slows, there is a distance of closest approach, then they begin to separate.   If the interaction between them is the Coulomb force, then the incoming charge goes slower and slower and slower, but never stops.   This is because the Coulomb force has infinite range.  It goes on forever, so the charges always repulse, less and less as they move away, but never getting to zero.